# How can I reduce the size of text in a cell with iTextSharp?

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, itext, font-size

I'm adding text and textBoxes to a table like so:

```
PdfPTable tblFirstRow = new PdfPTable(7);
tblFirstRow.WidthPercentage = 100;
tblFirstRow.SpacingBefore = 4f;
//tblFirstRow.LockedWidth = true;
float[] FirstRowWidths = new float[] { 137f, 138f, 175f, 100f, 50f, 175f, 225f };
tblFirstRow.SetWidths(FirstRowWidths);
tblFirstRow.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

// "Required Date"
Chunk reqDate = new Chunk("Required Date: ", timesRoman9Font);
Paragraph parReqDate = new Paragraph();
parReqDate.Add(reqDate);
PdfPCell cellReqDate = new PdfPCell(parReqDate);
cellReqDate.BorderWidth = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
tblFirstRow.AddCell(cellReqDate);

PdfPCell cellReqDateTextBox = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxReqDate"),
    Phrase = new Phrase("4/16/2015") //, // TODO: get current date
    //FixedHeight = 16
    // set borders, or other cell options here
};
tblFirstRow.AddCell(cellReqDateTextBox);
```

This pretty much works, but as you can see:

[image]

...the text ("4/16/2015") is outsized. How can I reduce the size of the text? Do I need to change the rectangle size within CellLayout somehow, which is:

```
public class DynamicTextbox : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    private string fieldname;

    public DynamicTextbox(string name)
    {
        fieldname = name;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].PdfWriter;

        // rectangle holds the dimensions and coordinates of the cell that was created
        // which you can then use to place the textfield in the correct location
        // and optionally fit the textfield to the size of the cell


        float textboxheight = 11f;
        // modify the rectangle so the textfield isn't the full height of the cell
        // in case the cell ends up being tall due to the table layout
        Rectangle rect = rectangle;
        rect.Bottom = rect.Top - textboxheight;

        TextField text = new TextField(writer, rect, fieldname);
        // set and options, font etc here

        PdfFormField field = text.GetTextField();

        writer.AddAnnotation(field);
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are making two mistakes (and I can only repeat that you should start reading the documentation after asking one trivial question after the other in the past week).

1. You are adding the date using a `Phrase`. Since you don't define a `Font`, the default font family is Helvetica, the style is regular and the font size is 12. Changing the height of the cell won't change anything. Changing the font will. How to change the font? That's explained in Chapter 2 of my book. For instance: `new Phrase("Font of 9 pt", new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 9))` will create text with a font of size 9 pt.
2. You are adding the date as a `Phrase`, but you cover that text with a text field. What is the rationale to do this? Is it your intention to allow people to change the date in the text field? In that case you need to set the text, the font and the font size at the level of the text field. If you create a text field with font size 0, then the font size will adapt to the size of the `Rectangle`, but in all other cases, the font size as defined is respected.

Comment: The "rationale" is I've adapted code that I've found. I see that I really have two textboxes (seemingly, anyway) everywhere - they are different sizes, and one has a colored background. I don't yet see what it is I need to remove from my code to prevent the second one from displaying, though. I did add the font (smaller) to the Phrase constructor to right-size the text in the textbox.

Comment: The one with the blue background (that disappears when you uncheck "highlight fields") is a widget annotation of a real text field (it's interactive). You may call the other one what you like if nobody else is around,  but please avoid to call that a text box or a text field in the presence of others. Since you've answered one question, I hope you'll answer this one too: why are you taking the slow path to create your application? Why don't you study iText/PDF first so that you can achieve your assignment in less time but with higher quality?

Comment: If I could find one that was truly iTextSharp-specific (C#), and not iText (Java)-specific, I would. I find too many differences between the two. It's like trying to read a German edition of "Huck Finn" by reading the Dutch version - doable, but too much constant meddlesome translation is involved.

Comment: That's not something a true developer would say. In high school I read books in Latin, Dutch, French and English alike. There's no problem with that, is there? Code is code is code, whether it's Java or C#.

Comment: According to your definition, then, I'm not "a true developer"; which is akin to being "a true believer" I guess, for those who idolize code. As to human languages, I know German well, and Spanish well enough to read it, but it still requires effort when reading them to translate them into my native tongue/"the language of my heart". A "true developer" may prefer your theoretical answers, but I (being a hack, pagan, or infidel) prefer the more concrete answers, which actually show how to accomplish the particular thing I'm after.

Comment: By using hacks, your code will be a patchwork of snippets of code. As a project leader, I try not to have developers who do not look at the whole picture on my team. I couldn't afford doing that at the start of my career, and I have seen some code that was really hard to maintain. I talk from experience. According to your definition, I should only ask/answer questions in Dutch, because English is only the 4th language I learned. Concepts such as leading, user units, font sizes,... are language-indifferent. By demanding answers to detail questions in C#, you slow down your development.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the DynamicTextbox() code to this:

```
PdfPCell cellReqDateTextBox = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxReqDate"),
    Phrase = new Phrase(GetCurrentDate(), timesRoman9Font) // <= tip to add explicit font from Bruno, the iText Whisperer
};
tblFirstRow.AddCell(cellReqDateTextBox);

public class DynamicTextbox : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    private string fieldname;

    public DynamicTextbox(string name)
    {
        fieldname = name;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].PdfWriter;
        TextField text = new TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
        PdfFormField field = text.GetTextField();
        writer.AddAnnotation(field);
    }
}
```

...works just fine:

[image]